# Retrieve data stored by childByAutoID in firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase i'm trying to retrieve data stored in the firebase realtime database by using the childByAutoID() to give the data a unique identifier but the problem is i'm not entirely sure how to achieve this?

```
func retData(){
    rootRef.child("users").child(userID).ChildByAutoID().observeEventType(.Value){
        (snap: FIRDataSnapshot) in

    self.simpleLabel.text = snap.value?.description

    }   
 }
```

Json data structure

```
-userID
   -childByAutoID
      -player1
         -email
```

Comment: Whats `userID` , becoz i dont see it in your Json tree

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to do. `ChildByAutoId()` is a method that you use when *writing* to the database, while `observeEventType()` is used for *reading*. Are you trying to listen for whenever a user is added to the list of users?

Comment: forgot to include it in the question, @FrankvanPuffelen just retrieve the data to a label.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON structure is:-

```
-users
  -childByAutoID
    -playerID
      -email
```

Use :-

```
 rootRef.child("users").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(snap) in

           if let userDict = snap.value as? [String:AnyObject]{

               for each in userDict as [String: AnyObject] {

                   let autoID = each.0
                   //Here you retrieve your autoID

                   rootRef.child("users").child(autoID).child("player1").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: {(playersDict) in
                      if let playerDictionary = playerDict.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
                        let emailID = playerDictionary["email"] as! String

                          //print(emailID)

                     }
             })
      }
   }
})
```

Comment: i submitted the wrong json structure for the question

Comment: nope its just prints out the entire json tree, when i try to print the output

Comment: thanks again but the code just wont run for some odd reason

Comment: it should say player1 and no its neither,  just a parent for email. also it just wont print anything in between where you said  print(emailID) in your answer

Comment: Answer updated, if it works, fine - other wise go to your DB console click on the three dots towards the top right side of the dashboard , click export JSON and paste it in your question as text .